# How can I implement patch HTTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, patch

I'm developing a web service with Microsoft Web API 2.

I've a person controller and I would handle patch HTTP request. Below my person controller:

```
namespace MyAssembly.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Person")]
    public class PersonController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAll(int id)
        {
            // get logic...
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Person/{id:int}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Create(int id, Person dto)
        {
            // post logic...
        }

    [HttpPatch]
    [Route("api/Person/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Update(int id, object dto)
    {
        Person currentPerson = myRepo.Get(id);

        currentPerson.patch(dto); // <-- How can I "patch" currentPerson object?

        myRepo.Update(id, currentPerson);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Below my person object:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int[] PreferredNumbers { get; set; }

    public string[] PreferredSerieTV { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

My Goal is to update all properties of `currentPerson` object with all specified properties inside `dto` object.

My HTTP patch request should be as following:

```
PATCH /api/Person/1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "Name": "Alessia",
    "PreferredNumbers": [1,2,3],
    "PreferredSerieTV": ["Serie1", "Serie2"]
}
```

I've tried use Delta object but there is a known problem with integer matrix. Previous my signature was like following:

```
public IHttpActionResult Update(int id, Delta<Person> dto) { ... }
```

*Nice to have: support lower-case property on http request.*

How can I handle patch request?

**[EDIT]**

I've integrated your solution but I obtain this error:

```
original
System.ArgumentException: 'Un oggetto di tipo 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' non può essere convertito nel tipo 'System.Int32[]'.'

traduction
System.ArgumentException: 'An object type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32[]'.'
```

the line of code that thown exception is this:

```
private static void updateObjectPropertyCore<TObject>(TObject target, string propertyName, object value) where TObject : class
{
    var type = typeof(TObject);
    var property = type.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(propertyName);
    if (property != null && property.CanWrite)
    {
        property.SetValue(target, value); <---
    }
}
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: Why `object dto` in patch action? Should not that be `Parson dto`?

Comment: Hi Nkosi, the dto object could be also of type Person. I can't see how using "Person" type could resolve the problem. Could you give me some hints? thanks

Comment: `but there is a known problem with integer matrix. Previous my signature was like following:` What is the known problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar for both PUT and PATCH requests.

To accept only properties to change refactor action to accept `IDictionary<string, object>` to hold the changed properties to update/patch.

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("api/Person/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> dto) { ... }
```

Reflection can then be used to access the matching properties with the help of the following extension methods

```
public static void patchObject<TObject>(this TObject target, Dictionary<string, object> values) where TObject : class {
    if (target != null) {
        foreach (var kvp in values) {
            updateObjectPropertyCore<TObject>(target, kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}

private static void updateObjectPropertyCore<TObject>(TObject target, string propertyName, object value) where TObject : class {
    var type = typeof(TObject);
    var property = type.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(propertyName);
    if (property != null && property.CanWrite) {
        object coercedValue;
        var destinationType = property.PropertyType;
        try {
            coercedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, destinationType, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        } catch {
            return destinationType.IsValueType ? null : Activator.CreateInstance(destinationType);
        }
        property.SetValue(target, coercedValue);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets a property by name, ignoring case and searching all interfaces.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">The type to inspect.</param>
/// <param name="propertyName">The property to search for.</param>
/// <returns>The property or null if not found.</returns>
public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(this Type type, string propertyName) {

    var typeList = new List<Type> { type };

    if (type.IsInterface()) {
        typeList.AddRange(type.GetInterfaces());
    }

    var flags = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    return typeList
        .Select(interfaceType => interfaceType.GetProperty(propertyName, flags))
        .FirstOrDefault(property => property != null);
}
```

So now you can just call the extension method on the object to be patched.

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("api/Person/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> dto) {
    var currentPerson = myRepo.Get(id);

    if(currentPerson == null)
        return NotFound();

    currentPerson.patchObject(dto); // <-- matching keys in dto will modify target object

    myRepo.Update(id, currentPerson);

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: @ilMattion ok that is a conversion issue. Let me look into that.

Comment: Hi, Any examples, ideas, on how to implement Patch for a list of objects? (eg.: approving / updating a status for multiple users at once, by getting the db users by the ids from the path) Thank you!